# Как получить параметры сессии?

Tags: node.js, redis, express-sessions

Есть структура файлов

[image: Структура]

где auth.js - модель авторизации в системе,
    wsserver.js-приёмник данных socket-a
В руте Index.js я проверяю наличие параметра сессии, и в зависимости от результата, рендерю страницу.
middlewares.js- необходимые настройки приложения(включая настройки сессии -код ниже)

```
redis=app.core.redis.createClient();
redis.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Redis client connected');
});
redis.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong ' + err);
});
RedisStore=app.core.connectredis(app.core.session);
global.app.sessionstore=new RedisStore({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, client: redis });

app.use(app.core.session({
    secret: "kqsdjfmlksdhfhzirzeoibrzecrbzuzefcuercazeafxzeokwdfzeijfxcerig",
    store: new RedisStore({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, client: redis })
}));
```

Самая большая загвоздка- это получить параметр сессии в auth.js

```
module.exports=
{
    CheckUser:function(login,password, callback){
        if(user){/*Устанавливаю сессию*/}
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметры сессии можно получить :
1) Используя глобальные переменные( но я так полагаю, что этот вариант не безопасен)
2) Используя запросы(потому что сессии передаются заголовками) передавая управление рутам
3) Копать там, где хранятся сессии(у меня это redis(хранилище данных)
Я выбрала второй вариант и, через ajax запросы стала передавать параметры в контроллер, который уже и имеет доступ к заголовкам